# Symfony2: $form->isValid() always returning true

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, silex

I'm having a problem with Symfony form validation (using Silex). I have a `repeated` input for a password reset form, which works fine if both passwords match. If they don't, however, `$form->isValid()` still returns true. `$form->getErrorsAsString()` is empty too.
After lots of googling and reading many answers to questions here that were more or less related, I still haven't found a solution.

**Update: After checking out various versions from my Git repository, I eventually found out the feature broke when I updated Symfony from version `2.5.7` to version `2.6.0` released yesterday. I looked at the changelog and didn't see anything that would break this. I temporarily switched back, but would eventually like to be able to use version `2.6.0`...**

Here's the `buildForm` method defined for my `PasswordResetType`:

```
function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => $this->app['translator']->trans('form_errors.pass_must_match'),
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new Assert\NotBlank()
                    ),
                ),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new Assert\NotBlank()
                    )
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

The Twig template associated to my form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.password.first, 'user.new_password'|trans, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.password.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'user.new_password'|trans}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.password.second, 'user.new_password_confirmation'|trans, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.password.second) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.password.second, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'user.new_password_confirmation'|trans}}) }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{'user.reset_password'|trans}}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The associated controllers:

```
$app->get('/{_locale}/reset_password/{token}', function(Request $request, $token) use ($app) {
    /* ... */

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(new PasswordResetType($app), array())->getForm();

    return $app['twig']->render('password_reset.twig', array(
        'title' => 'Page title',
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
})->bind('reset_password');

$app->post('/{_locale}/reset_password/{token}', function(Request $request, $token) use ($app) {
    /* ... */

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(new PasswordResetType($app), array())->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $password = $data['password']; // this is line 113

        /* ... */
    }
});
```

This generates the following error when passwords don't match: `Error: ContextErrorException in controllers_users.php line 113: Notice: Undefined index: password`. This indicates `$form->isValid()` returned `true` while it shouldn't have, since the passwords don't match.

Update: I opened a bug report: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12792

Comment: try removing constraints, as they dont make sence there

Comment: Well, I just found the origin: it broke when I updated Symfony from version `2.5.7` to version `2.6.0`. I temporarily switched back, but would like to be able to use the new version. Didn't see anything about this in the changelog, unfortunately.

About those constraints though, I thought `'required' => true` would only add the attributes in the browser, but if I get what you're saying, it also works for the validator? I tried removing them, but the problem persists.

Comment: Just tried it out by manually removing the `required` attribute in the form and my intuition was correct: those do not do the same thing. It allowed me to submit the form with both fields blank, so one is for the browser, the other for the validator.

Comment: just tested this on my Symfony 2.6 project without Silex, and it seems the validation works fine, i just used `createForm()` instead of `createBuilder()`

Comment: I tried using `createForm()`, but I got an error saying the method doesn't exist. Looking at the documentation, the examples always use `$formFactory->createBuilder()->getForm()`. What does your code look like exactly?

Comment: Oh nevermind, found the `create()` method. Still doesn't work though. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess I'll wait for an update or something, since it looks like this is a bug.

Comment: Please report if it's an issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues

Comment: I'll definitely do that, but it seems a bit odd, since @dimention wasn't able to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in Symfony, which was fixed in version 2.6.6. See my [bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12792) on GitHub for more information.